Docutils AttributeError while using sphinx to build a document
Description
I am currently using sphinx to build a document for an existing project, When I am trying to use make html to build, something went error.
It says:
File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/doc/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docutils/parsers/rst/states.py", line 2933, in eof
    if self.memo.section_bubble_up_kludge:
AttributeError: 'Struct' object has no attribute 'section_bubble_up_kludge'

Environments
Here are my python environments.
Python 3.8.19

Package                       Version
----------------------------- ---------
alabaster                     0.7.13
Babel                         2.15.0
certifi                       2024.7.4
charset-normalizer            3.3.2
colorama                      0.4.6
commonmark                    0.9.1
docutils                      0.18.1
idna                          3.7
imagesize                     1.4.1
importlib_metadata            8.0.0
Jinja2                        3.1.4
livereload                    2.7.0
markdown-it-py                3.0.0
MarkupSafe                    2.1.5
mdit-py-plugins               0.4.1
mdurl                         0.1.2
myst-parser                   3.0.1
numpy                         1.24.4
packaging                     24.1
pillow                        10.4.0
pip                           24.0
Pygments                      2.18.0
pytz                          2024.1
PyYAML                        6.0.1
recommonmark                  0.7.1
requests                      2.32.3
setuptools                    69.5.1
snowballstemmer               2.2.0
Sphinx                        6.1.3
sphinx-autobuild              2021.3.14
sphinx-rtd-theme              2.0.0
sphinxcontrib-applehelp       1.0.4
sphinxcontrib-devhelp         1.0.2
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp        2.0.1
sphinxcontrib-jquery          4.1
sphinxcontrib-jsmath          1.0.1
sphinxcontrib-qthelp          1.0.3
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml 1.1.5
tornado                       6.4.1
tqdm                          4.66.4
urllib3                       2.2.2
wheel                         0.43.0
zipp                          3.19.2

Attempts

Reinstall the whole environmet, currently I have create a virtual environment for building the documents, it doesn't work.
Degrade the docutils version, lots of version have been tried except those aren't compatible with the shpinx verison, it's seems this solution didn't work in my case.

I have no idea what's going on, for I have successfully build documents for another project, the configuration seems to be no problem.

The "section_bubble_up_kludge" attribute of the docutils.states.RSTStateMachine.memo structure is initialized in the docutils.states.RSTStateMachine.run() function since 2002-10-18. Maybe some extension subclasses the RSTStateMachine and doesn't initialize its memo attribute?

Does the "existing project" come with the Sphinx documentation? Did others experience the same problem?

The "myst" parser seems to contain or have contained the "section_bubble_up_kludge" in a Mock StateMachine: https://myst-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/myst_parser/mocking.html. Maybe trying a different version there may help...

A full backtrace might help to find the source of this problem!
